# Dense Zeta Curve

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

In Reference 4 of this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_universality#cite_ref-4), it is stated that
the curve $\{(\zeta(\sigma+it),\zeta^{(1)}(\sigma+it), \cdots, \zeta^{(n-1)}(\sigma+it))|t\in\mathbb R\}$ is dense in $\mathbb C^n$ if $\frac12 <\sigma < 1$.

- Is it known if the curve is still dense for *some* $\sigma\notin (\frac12,1)$?
- In particular, what if $\sigma=\frac12$?
- In particular, what if $\sigma=\frac12$ and $n=1$? i.e. is $\zeta(\frac12+it)$ dense in $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the further notes at the end of Chapter XI to that reference (Titchmarsh "Theory of the Riemann Zeta Function")

> "The problem of the distribution of values of $\zeta(1/2+it)$ is
>   rather different from that of $\zeta(\sigma+i t)$ with $1/2<\sigma<1$.
>   In the first place it is not know whether the values of $\zeta(1/2+i
> t)$ are everywhere dense, though one would conjecture so.  Second,
>   there is a difference in the rates of growth with respect to $t$..."

He then explains that for fixed $\sigma>1/2$, the values of $\log(\zeta(\sigma+i t))$ have a limiting distribution according to a theorem of Bohr and Jessen.  On the other hand a theorem of Selberg states that the values of $\log(\zeta(1/2+it))$ *when divided by $\sqrt{1/2\log(\log(t))}$*, are distributed like a Gaussian.